# Save or create new record if not existing already using Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am recursively calling a function which inserts new records to DB, but also deleting from DB in some part of it. To understand me better, I am providing my function:

```
public function updateUserMailQueue($data, $user_id) {
    if(!array_key_exists('mail_queue', $data)) return;
    $queues = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', '', $data['mail_queue']);
    $queues = explode(',', $queues);
    sort($queues);
    foreach($queues as $queue) {
        if(empty($queue)) continue;
        $existing = MailQueue::zQuery()->where('order', $queue)->first();
        if(empty($existing)) {
            $existing = new MailQueue();
            $existing->order = $queue;
        } else if($existing->user_id != $user_id) {
            $this->updateUserMailQueue(['mail_queue' => $existing->order + 1], $existing->user_id);
        }
        $existing->user_id = $user_id;
        $existing->save();
    }
    MailQueue::zQuery()->where('user_id', $user_id)->whereNotIn('order', $queues)->delete();
}
```

What I am trying to achieve whit this function is to create priority order by which mail are going to be sent to user (lower number higher priority). The reason I am using recursion is because if order is changed so user with priority order of 4 becomes 1, I need to change priority order for all other users. The problem I am facing in a function written like it is now, last line in a function deletes `$existing` record which was assigned in a call before, so once it is back to that call, next two lines are called: 

`$existing->user_id = $user_id;
$existing->save();`

but since `$existing` record no longer exists in table, nothing is being saved, but also no error is being thrown. Now, what I would like to know is if there is a way to do something like `->saveOrCreate()` instead of `->save()` for this kind problem?

Comment: `->updateOrCreate([ ['order' => $queu], ['mail_queue' => $existing->order + 1] ] ]);`

Comment: u need `MailQueue::firstOrCreate([ ['order' => $queue], ['user_id' => $user_id] ] ]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need eloquent `updateOrCreate` method,

> You may also come across situations where you want to **update** an existing model or **create** a new model if **none exists**. Laravel provides an **updateOrCreate** method to do this in one step. Like the firstOrCreate method, updateOrCreate persists the model, so there's **no need to call save()**:

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
  ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
  ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

How it works ?:

```
App\YourModel::updateOrCreate(
  param1,
  param2
);
```

If all key and values in the `param1(Array)` match, This row will be updated by **`param2`** key=>values, (Don't need to repeat param1 key values for param2 ),Otherwise A new row will be created.

Comment: New row with both param1 and param2 key=>values?

Comment: yeah , Eloquent will handle this, no need to repeat. New record contains both arrays,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateOrCreate` method provided in laravel.

**Example**: If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99. It will create new one if there is no existing.

```
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
     ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
     ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1] );
```